# Curvature of a function of positive definite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, positive-definite

Say that $M$ is a positive definite matrix, and we consider the mapping:
$$X \mapsto \|X^{-1/2} M X^{-1/2} \| $$
Above, $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the largest signular value/operator norm. Is this function convex on the set of positive definite matrices?

I ask, because it is true in the scalar case, $x \mapsto \frac{m}{x}$ is convex when $m > 0$ and $x > 0$. When $M$ and $X$ are both diagonal, it is convex:
$$
\max \frac{m_i}{x_i},
$$
which is the composition of an increasing convex function ($\max$) with convex functions $x \mapsto m_i/x_i$. Thus, convex.

Comment: Check this for diagonal matrices $X$ (this probably will suffice).

Comment: In the case $M$ is also diagonal, then it is since then the function is $\max\{m_i/x_i\}$, which is composition of convex function increasing function with convex functions, therefore convex.